# data getting inserted twice in database - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I've spent hours on trying to fix this one. every time I upload a file. all the data/id3 tags are being inserted twice on my database. before it was working properly now it has this bug and I badly need some help now.

In my controller I am executing update at the same time since I want also to update the data inserted into database with the details from the id3 tags.

**Controller**

```
public function save()
{
    $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $status = $this->input->post('status');
    $original_file = $this->input->post('original_file');
    $revised_file = $this->input->post('revised_file');

    $song_data = array(
            'user_id' => $id,
            'song_info_status' => $status,
            'song_info_file_name' => $original_file,
            'song_info_revised_file_name' => $revised_file,
            'song_info_date_added' => 'now()',
            'song_info_date_updated' => 'now()'
            );

    $song_info_id = $this->song_info_model->save($song_data);
    $composer_data = array(
        'composer_name' => ''
    );

    $composer_id = $this->composer_model->save($composer_data);
    $song_composer_data = array(
        'song_info_id' => $song_info_id,
        'composer_id' => $composer_id
    );

    $this->song_composer_model->save($song_composer_data);
    $status_data = array(
        'song_info_id' => $song_info_id
    );

    $status_id = $this->status_model->save($status_data);

    $tags_info = array();
    $tags_info = $this->getTagsInfo(FCPATH ."temp" . "/" .$revised_file);





    if(isset($tags_info['Author']))
    {
       // echo iconv("UTF-8","EUC-JP", $tags_info['Author']);
        //echo $str = mb_convert_encoding($tags_info['Author'], "UTF-8", "auto");
        $status_data = array(
            'status_artist_name' => $tags_info['Author']
        );

        $this->status_model->update($status_data, $status_id);
    }
    if(isset($tags_info['Title']))
    {

        $song_data = array(
            'song_info_original_title' => $tags_info['Title']
        );
        $this->song_info_model->update($song_data, $song_info_id);
    }
    rename($this->source.$revised_file, $this->destination.$revised_file);  
}
```

In my model I am just getting the data I have from my controller. there's no loop or anything and I really can't find the culprit.

**Model**

```
 public function save($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('song_info', $data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
}

public function update($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('song_info_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('song_info', $data);
}
```

Comment: Apparently, somehow you are calling the save() function in model twice. Which model is it?

Comment: @Penguine as you can see those are from different models.

Comment: If you are calling from client side , using any javascript, make sure you are not calling it twice.

Comment: yeah. lol. thank you so much! haha. I never thought of that at the first place. then I checked my footer.php I have duplicated my upload.js. well thank you. @chinmayahd